# Set onClickListener for every single listview element

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-listview

Here's how my app works. User records a sound and then gives it a certain name. In this example I'll be recording two sound files. Test1.mp3 and Test2.mp3. After I'm done recording for the first time, a dialog appears and I type in 'Test1', same goes for the second recording. Test1.mp3 and Test2.mp3 were now added to the listview. This is the code:

```
//filename is a variable for the name of the file, these lines execute everytime I record a new file
ArrayList<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<String>();
fileNames.add(filename.toString()); 
listView = (ListView) findViewById (R.id.mainListView);
listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplerow, fileNames);
listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

So, after I've recorded both files and they're added to listview, I want to set onClickListeners to both listview elements. But how do I do it? How do I make it so that everytime a new recorded file has been added to the listview, it also automatically generates the onclick method. This wouldn't be as complicated but every recorded file, ofcourse, has a different path.

The code now:

```
//LISTVIEW
    fileNames.add(filename.toString()); //adding each filename to ArrayList<String>
    listView = (ListView) findViewById (R.id.mainListView);
    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplerow, fileNames);
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), filename, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }

    });
```

This is the code that executes each time new file is recorded

Comment: You mean like an [`onItemClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to add a new listener every time you add an element to the list.
You can use a `OnItemClickListener` set once and for all, and you will be able to find the item that has been clicked by the index in the callback function

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3)
```

which is, parameter `int position`.

Inside onItemClick implementation, you can then retrieve the element which has been clicked by

```
arg0.getItemAtPosition(position)
```

Also, you don't have to add the onItemClickListener every time, you can just prepare it once in the onCreate method of your Activity and never change it.

What you will need to do instead, is making a new adapter (or adding a new item to the adapter) when your new file recording has terminated.

I prepared an almost full sample to show how to use the ListView:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final ArrayList<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    fileNames.add("Test1.mp3");
    fileNames.add("Test2.mp3");

    final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById (R.id.mainListView);
    ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, fileNames);
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                    (String)arg0.getItemAtPosition(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();   
        }
    });
}
```

This is enough if the items in the list do not change.

When a recording of your next mp3 file terminates, and you want to add an item to the list, you may just do:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById (R.id.mainListView);
fileNames.add("Test3.mp3");
((ArrayAdapter<String>)listView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Replace "Test3" with your new recorded mp3's filename, and it will show up in the list.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried doing it but something isn't working right. I added toast to see if it works but it doesn't. When I record Test1.mp3, it shows Test1 when I click on the item, but then when I record Test2, both items show Test2, if you know what I mean. Any idea what could be done wrong? I don't quite get the arg0.getItemAtPosition part

Comment: It is weird that when you add a second item to the list the first item changes.  Can you post the code where you add new elements to the list?  My guess is that there are some issues in the way that part is implemented.

Comment: Sorry, now I understand what you meant.  You probably meant that in your Toast message, you just keep getting the same filename, which is because you did not get the clicked item by arg.getItemAtPosition(position).  I edited my answer with an almost-full working sample, please check it out ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {

   switch(position){
    case 0:
    blablbla
    break;
    case1 1:
    blabla
    break;
    /....
    }
    }):
```